# For loop for in python not working

Tags: python-2.7, loops, for-loop

Im trying to implement this function.

```
def eq_chars(s,i):
"""Returns: length of sequence of equal characters starting at s[i].
Examples: eq_chars('aaaxxyx',0) is 3 and eq chars('aaaxxyx',5) is 1
Precondition: s is a string, 0 <= i < len(s).""
```

"

My code thus far has been this:

```
    for i in range(len(s)):
        accumulator = 0
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            accumulator = accumulator + 1
            return accumulator
        else:
            pass
```

I know there is a problem in the beginning of the for loop. I stands for the index which will be given to us. Can you possibly change variables? What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning when the if statement is satisfied and at the beginning of the loop you are losing the value of i. The correct code should be:

```
def eq_chars(s, i):
    accumulator = 1
    for j in range(i, len(s) - 1):
        if s[j] == s[j+1]:
            accumulator += 1
        else:
            break
    return accumulator
```

This function start from the given index, and checks if the next character is the same with the current one. If it finds a match it increases the count. When a non-matching character is seen, it stops the loop and returns the count.

Comment: I see, it makes much more sense now. I'm curious as to how you got the range( i , len(s) -1). Would you mind explaining it a bit more?

Comment: Since the function returns the length of sequence of equal characters starting at `s[i]`, the loop should start from the `i`th index. That's where `range(i,` part came from. Moreover, we are checking whether `s[j]` is equal to `s[j+1]`, so if we write range(i, len(s)), then, in the last iteration, the `j+1`th index will be out of the strings range. Therefore, we must loop until `len(s)-1`. That's why we should write `range(i,len(s)-1)`.